# SQL syntax error. check corresponds to MYSQL server

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I try to do a form which can insert data into database. After I insert a dummy data the is come out.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

This error are make me in trouble. My database are not inserted any record

```
<?php

    $db = "assignment";
    $table = "column";

    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysqli_select_db($conn,$db);

        $Title = $_POST['title'];
        $Author = $_POST['author'];
        $Country = $_POST['country'];
        $Date = $_POST['date'];
        $Abstract = $_POST['abstract'];
        $Problem = $_POST['rproblem'];
        $Aim = $_POST['raim'];
        $Objectives = $_POST['robjective'];
        $Type = $_POST['rstudies'];

    if(isset($_POST['rmethod'])){
        $method = implode(",",$_POST['rmethod']);
    }else{
        $method = "";
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO '$table' (title,author,country,date,abstract,rproblem,raim,robjective,rstudies,rmethod)
            VALUES ('$Title','$Author,'$Country','$Date','$Abstract','$Problem','$Aim','$Objectives','$Type','$method')";

    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }else{
        echo "Data Added";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set your `$table` variable inside single quotes while using a [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html), `column` for your table name `$table = "column";`

Use backticks around it, like so:

```
INSERT INTO `$table`
```

either do that or give your table another name.

- [**Read the manual about table and column identifiers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html)

---

You also have a quote missing here `'$Author,` so do `'$Author',`

Also, you can remove `mysqli_query($conn,$sql);` since you're already using
`if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))`

---

**Footnotes:**

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). I strongly suggest that you use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: now the new error are come out.
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Malaysia','','','','','','Observational','')' at line 2

Comment: @WilliamLee You also have a quote missing here `'$Author,` so do `'$Author',`

Comment: @WilliamLee you need to accept/upvote helpful answers

Comment: I was going nuts with a similar problem. In my case, I had `Load='test'` and as soon as I changed it to `\`Load\`='test'` it worked.

Comment: @Morfinismo I have to admit that I also ventured down that road at the beginning. From then on, I found the reference for it, and ["LOAD" is indeed a MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L). Glad to know that the Q&A here served you well, *cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table (title,author,country,date,abstract,rproblem,raim,robjective,rstudies,rmethod)
            VALUES ('$Title','$Author','$Country','$Date','$Abstract','$Problem','$Aim','$Objectives','$Type','$method')";
```

The table name or column name must enclose them in back-ticks (`) and not in single quotes or double quotes. Otherwise don't wrap them.Simply try like above.And if you are using reserved keywords as table name or column name then you must enclose them in back-ticks.And its better not to use any reserve keyword.So if you can change the name then it will be the best choice.You are using two reserve keywords in your query. Your table name and date column. Both are keywords

You can [check my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951632/insert-an-array-into-table-using-for-loop/24951716#24951716) for more

Comment: but there are still the same problem.

Comment: can you post the error message you are getting and try to echo your query and see what query is executing

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Malaysia','','','','','','Observational','')' at line 2

Comment: you are missing the closing quotes of `'$Author`

Answer (score 0):

Follow other answer you also missing `'` on `$author`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` (title,author,country,date,abstract,rproblem,raim,robjective,rstudies,rmethod)
            VALUES ('$Title','$Author','$Country','$Date','$Abstract','$Problem','$Aim','$Objectives','$Type','$method')";
```

Also better use to replace

```
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
```

to

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (!$result){
```

else your query will execute two time.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah thanks dude for clear i am bit confuse about this

Comment: You're welcome Rakesh. This one was a bit confusing, I must admit.